# Persist Java 8 LocalTime in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-time

I have a Java 8 LocalTime in one of my entity .

```
private final LocalTime departureTime;
```

It is a Spring Boot 1.3.6 application with Spring Data Rest . I use Jsr310JpaConverters to support Java 8 time module for JPA .

When I save the LocalTime variable to MySql , date at which the LocalTime variable is saved is also being persisted to the database . Suppose if I save 18:00:00 on 1st Jan 2016 , it is persisted as 2016-01-01 18:00:00 . I want to save only the time . ie 18:00:00 . Any solutions ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: in your database, change the type of your field in which you want to save time. change the type from DateTime to time.

Comment: who created the database table? what annotations are on that field? Clearly "final" fields are not supported in JPA standard.

Comment: DDL is managed by Spring/JPA/Hibernate

Comment: and unless you tell people WHAT annotations you put on that field and what schema it created, how can they tell YOU anything?

Comment: No annotations in the LocalTime field .

Comment: so perhaps there ought to be annotations there?! How does your JPA provider know how you want to map it? Which converter is "Jsr310JpaConverters" going to use for that java type by default?

Comment: What annotations should I use ?

Comment: errm `@Temporal` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120659/discussion-between-fahad-fazil-and-neil-stockton).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exemple runs with: java 8, JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.5.

You can implement a JPA AttributeConverter, if you are using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate earlier release of 5.0 version:

```
import java.sql.Time;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

/**
 * Converter to persist LocalDate and LocalDateTime with 
 * JPA 2.1 and Hibernate older than 5.0 version
 **/

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, Time>{

    @Override
    public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime localTime) {
        return (localTime == null ? null : Time.valueOf(localTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Time time) {
        return (time == null ? null : time.toLocalTime()); 
    }

}
```

Or if you are using Hibernate 5.0 (or later) you can add the dependency of maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Notes -> The mapping of the entities is the same.

Answer (score 2):

"Jsr310JpaConverters" offers only a small subset of the possible range of `AttributeConverter`s that a typical project would need for handling `java.time` types. Sadly its [LocalTimeConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/threeten/Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalTimeConverter.html) (presumably what is used here), converts to `(java.util.)Date`, so you get the time+date stored.

One solution would be to write your own JPA 2.1 `AttributeConverter` for `java.time.LocalTime` that converts it to `java.sql.Time`.

Other `JPA` providers (e.g `DataNucleus`) provide such things out of the box.